# Install4j setting the file association of my exe to a file extension

Tags: install4j

Ive written a pdf viewer and used install4J to create an exe launcher.  I'd like to prompt to change the file association for .pdf to be my exe.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far to accomplish this and any errors you are getting with your efforts?

Answer (score 0):

Add a "File associations" screen to your installer and then a "Create a file association" action to the "Installation" screen. The "File associations" screen will pick up the action and ask the user if the action should be performed.

Comment: This does not work on Windows 10 with .pdf file extension.  Windows 10 resets the file association to MS Edge when install4j attempts to set it to the new application.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Windows 10 has protection mechanisms for changing important associations. I don't know of a workaround.

Comment: @IngoKegel have there been any updates to this? We still have a lot of users complaining about not being able to set the .pdf file association on Windows 10 / 11.

Other applications seem to have workarounds now (i.e. Acrobat, Foxit, etc...)

Comment: No, there is no update.

Comment: We did some research and came across this developer project that was able to make it work. https://kolbi.cz/blog/2017/10/25/setuserfta-userchoice-hash-defeated-set-file-type-associations-per-user/?sfw=pass1632402728. Surely you guys should be able to do the same?...

Comment: We would really not like to reverse engineer stuff to circumvent a restriction where Microsoft states “it is by design” and “this is a security measure”